# How can I have a script run whenever I start a zoom meeting?

Tags: bash, scripts, automation

I'm trying to write a script that will execute when I start a zoom meeting.

I found a command `wmctrl -l` which outputs

```
0x05e00020  0              N/A Zoom - Free Account
```

But, I can't figure out what to do with that information to execute a script when it's detected.

I'm not sure if I can utilize inotify or something else.

My operating system is Kubuntu 20.04

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to do?

Comment: When I join a zoom meeting I want to execute a script that interacts with my home automation to turn on lights in my office. I like to work with the office dark, it's more relaxing. But, that does not work so well with the zoom meetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to answer this question too, but nothing seemed forthcoming.  I realized, though, that I had already scripted some lua things to set Zoom's windows to be "always on top" and pinned to every workspace.  That led me on a journey.

### Here's the process

#### 1. install packages

```
sudo apt install devilspie2 lua-sec
```

#### 2. config devilspie2

and add this (or something like it) here: `~/.config/devilspie2/window_works.lua`

```lua
if (string.find(get_window_name(),"Zoom")) then
    debug_print("Window: " .. get_window_name());
    pin_window();

    require("socket")
    local https = require("ssl.https")
    local body, code, headers, status = https.request("https://api.duckduckgo.com/api")
    debug_print(body)
end
```

NOTE: you can also simply run a BASH script if that is easier:

```
local command = "/bin/bash /home/[username]/scripts/thing.sh"
os.execute(command)
```

#### 3. Profit!

When you open a new Zoom meeting (or something that matches the window name "Zoom"), that lua will run and it will pin the window (which you may or may not want) and it will then make an HTTP request.

### relevant documentation

- https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/9yt88g/always_on_visible_workspace_by_default/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22831701/lua-read-beginning-of-a-string (this can be handy to fuzzy match window names)
- http://notebook.kulchenko.com/programming/https-ssl-calls-with-lua-and-luasec

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect! KDE lets me add actions when it sees windows but I can't interact with the systems sound settings and send MQTT messages from the windows action settings.